# Xamarin form: How to override the OnBackButtonPressed on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, navigation, back-button

The OnBackButtonPressed doesn't get called. I have looked at other places, the function worked on android hardware back button. I wanted to alert user to enter the pin before they can go back to previous screen. My page was not a normal page. It's a tab page.. What should I do to override the navigation back button on iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the default back button with a custom back button, Xamarin Forms’s Navigation Bar is mapped to the `UINavigationBar` in iOS so you need to set custom back button to `UILeftBarButtonItem` like below

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    var backBtn = new UIButton(UIButtonType.Custom)
    {
        // setup your custom back button with title, image etc
    }
    backBtn.TouchDown += (sender, e) =>
    {
        //Handle back click here
    };

    NavigationController.TopViewController.
    NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem(backBtn);
}
```

You also need to bridge between Native to Forms so that you can get a callback in your Xamarin PCL or shared project.

There is a full implementation with code in this [article](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/03/12/lets-override-navigation-bar-back-button-click-in-xamarin-forms/)